# Eclipse dead code warning - why am I getting it?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-7

In the following loop, `listeners` is array list. Eclipse shows me warning `i++` being dead code. I have now added full for loop at its entirety as it exists in the code. Listeners are passed to the function and I don't think there is a way for Eclipse to detect if the list is empty

```
for (int i = 0; i < listeners.size(); i++) {
  listener = getMessageListener(i);
  while (listener.isMessageAvailable()) {
    fireJob(listener);
  }
  log.info("Placed all the pending jobs because of termination signal");
}
```

However following simple loop does not generate same warning

```
for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
    System.out.println(y);
}
```

To me, both look functionally same - standard for loop. Eclipse is very specific about highlighting `i++` area and fix is to remove `i++`.

Another observation is if I copy same loop to somewhere else, I don't get warning. So one possibility is eclipse could be thinking for whatever reasons loop won't be executed. But code in the block gets executed.

Comment: That `// do something` ***might*** be important. You don't have a `return;` statement buried in there, do you? You're asking "why is this code not working" but we can't tell based on your snippet. Please fix this by creating and posting your [mcve].

Comment: Maybe Eclipse is able to detect that `listeners.size() = 0` always.

Comment: We would need more code than what you've provided.

Comment: Did you try to clean & build the whole project? Is it still happening ?

Comment: Check that before your for loop, listeners is guaranteed to be empty , for example : do you have listeners.clear(); ? and before this for loop you didn't add any listener to the list?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, I'll be glad to provide the example if I could reproduce it. As mentioned in the post, it does happen only at this area and no where else. May be some obscure bug in eclipse or my stupidty. I have now provided the entire for loop

Comment: Eclipse thinks that your while loop won't end. What will make the listener no longer have an available message? And what type of threading are you doing here?

Comment: Are you changing the size of `listeners` in any functions you're calling inside  the loop?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, there is no threading involved, no one changes the list. I have exact same loops in other functions and it does not generate warning. Only this place.

Comment: I don't honestly know. I've voted to re-open, but still request that you try to simplify and isolate your problem, including cutting out code until you can isolate the problem into the smallest code that compiles (other than that warning) and that illustrates the problem.

Comment: @Laerte, no that's the entire loop, listeners size is determined at startup and never changes.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, may be just my luck - I got this obscure issue, I hate warnings in the code as many times they point to important issues and was banging my head. Finally decided to post the question to ruin reputation by getting all these minus points. I'll try my best to reproduce, but so far no luck

Comment: Include the code where `listeners` is defined. Don't know if vote to reopen given that no one has been able to replicate the behavior with the code included in the question.

Comment: @Alfabravo, I understand and if you look at my comments, I am also not able to reproduce the behavior anywhere else. I would also vote to close the question given that I am not able to reproduce it anywhere else. I am going with the assumption that this is some obscure bug in eclipse.

Comment: @user871199 don't give up, it is both intriguing  (as evidenced by the q being reopened!) and important to fix in Eclipse if you have found a bug. Two things to sanity check (just trying to suggest something!), 1. does javac give the warning, 2. have you stepped through that particular code and made sure it really does loop. The second one is important, because if a warning is being generated incorrectly, it is altogether possible that code is being compiled incorrectly too!

Answer (score 1):

One thought: if you comment out the `log.info(...` line does the warning go away? Because if Eclipse is determining that something is causing the loop to terminate early it must be because of one of the following:

1. the condition is always false. But that would make the body unreachable, so an *Unreachable code* error on the body. *Not your case*

   e.g.: in this example `y++` is *Dead code*, but body is *Unreachable code*.

   ```
   for (int y = 0; false; y++) {
       System.out.println(y);
   }
   ```
2. some statement before the last statement is terminating your loop. But then some of the body would be unreachable or dead. *Not your case*

   e.g.: in this example `y++` is *Dead code*, and the `println` in *Unreachable code*.

   ```
   for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
       break;
       System.out.println(y);
   }
   ```

   in this example `y++` and `println` is *Dead code*.

   ```
   for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
       if (true) {
           break;
       }
       System.out.println(y);
   }
   ```
3. last statement terminates the loop. That would make only the `i++` *Dead code*. *Not your case*, but should be testable that it isn't your case by commenting out the last statement.

   e.g.: in this example only `y++` is *Dead code*, but commenting out the `break` means there is no *Dead code*.

   ```
   for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
       System.out.println(y);
       break;
   }
   ```

So, I believe, if commenting out the last statement (`log` line in your case) in the loop does not make the *Dead code* warning go away you must have found a bug in the warnings generator/compiler. If so, I hope you can reduce it for all our sakes so that a proper bug report can be submitted.